# How to block execution of tasks till all tasks have been submitted?

Tags: python-3.x, dask, dask-distributed

I'm building a framework where every task is submitted to a user-supplied dask client using submit, like so:

```py
future = client.submit(my_func,*args)
```

Some functions have multiple dependencies on previous futures, with the deepest depth being about ~10-15 tasks deep. All of these functions are submitted to the client using the `submit` functionality.

However, I'm finding that with large amounts of tasks, say above a few thousand, this approach tends to hang the scheduler, as both computation and task submissions are happening concurrently. Is there a way to 'submit' something to the client in a delayed manner such that I can tell the client to execute only after every task has been submitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the dask.delayed interface, which is mostly the same as `client.submit`, but lazy.

https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/delayed.html

However, submitting a few thousand tasks shouldn't be that big of a tax on the scheduler.  If your tasks don't include a ton of metadata then I would expect the overhead to be about a second.

https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/delayed-best-practices.html#avoid-repeatedly-putting-large-inputs-into-delayed-calls

Comment: how would I tell the delayed annotation to specifically use the client available in the scope where my function is called?

Comment: You can manage schedulers within dask.config.  See https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/scheduling.html .  However if you only have one client (common case) then that will be used by default, and so you don't need to worry about it.